# tweepy twitter autotweet for other accounts

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have created python script to autotweet using my twitter account

how can I add another accounts to do the same (autotweet) using just the email and password?

I am using tweepy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you had to obtain the consumer key, consumer secret, access token and access token secret to tweet from your existing account.  You have to do the same for the others as well. I don't think you can use just the email and password associated with the twitter account

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Comment: yes I did that for my account, but I see some websites that can autotweet for you and you have to give them authorization ( they have a button when you click it it redirect you to twitter website and ask you for authorization )
then they can tweet without giving the website my keys and tokens

Comment: I found it here https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=XXXXXXXXX , but how can I get the oauth token?

Comment: You have to create an app on twitter and you will get specific consumer key and consumer secret of that app.